# How to include an enumeration in complexType?

Tags: xsd

**Kindly let me know if this is the correct way of including enumeration:**
**How do i restrict the error type to A, E, I and W**

```
<xsd:complexType name="Errors">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Error" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="ErrorType">
                                <xsd:simpleType>
                                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                    <xsd:maxLength value="1"/>
                                        <xsd:minLength value="1"/> 
                                        <xsd:enumeration value="E"/>
                                        <xsd:enumeration value="A"/>
                                        <xsd:enumeration value="W"/>
                                        <xsd:enumeration value="I"/>
                                    </xsd:restriction>
                                </xsd:simpleType>
                            </xsd:element>
                            <xsd:element name="ErrorMsgTxt">
                                <xsd:simpleType>
                                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                        <xsd:maxLength value="4000"/>
                                    </xsd:restriction>
                                </xsd:simpleType>
                            </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Your code answers your question.

Comment: Is it correct? Please tell me

Comment: You can test it here in this [fiddle](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/?save=3ec5cff2-1d9c-4cef-85a6-b8a2ace6e855-xsdvalidation#.U312WlhdVdo).

Comment: Yes that is how you include enumeration.
And yes that is how you can restrict the error type.